# PyUSB library using too much CPU time

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb

I have a piece of code that continuously monitors a USB HID device for input.The device is a infrared receiver for a remote control.

I am trying to program using **PyUSB** which is a python wrapper for **libusb** to monitor the remote key press.

To constantly monitor the device for inputs, I added the following lines of code

```
while 1:
    try:
        data = dev.read(ep.bEndpointAddress, ep.wMaxPacketSize*2)
        data=data.tolist()           
        key=join_int(data)                              #Join the elements of list
        print "Key is " , key
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        pass
```

The code uses a lot of CPU time on checking using **top**.

Is there a way to reduce the CPU usage.Adding sleep() is one way but that might miss keystrokes if I am not wrong.

Comment: Have you checked out the select module?

Comment: No I am not sure what you are talking about.Could you explain a bit?

Comment: ``poll`` and ``select`` are normally the answers to waiting, without busy-looping, for external input on *nixen (for Windows it's ``WaitForMultipleObjects`` or some such).

Comment: If you pass a timeout parameter to `read`, then it will doing a blocking read for that amount of time, which will not consume cpu.  If you get no data after timeout just loop and call `read` again.  This is similar to `sleep`, but you won't miss any data.

Comment: the timeout seems to be working well.THanks